# Making a PWA, can I use bootstrap+jquery?

Tags: jquery, progressive-web-apps

I'm about to develop a PWA for our Company. I've been doing Web Applications so i'm so used to Bootstrap and Jquery. I'd like to develop the PWA in the same fashion. I can make the app a SPA with Jquery by simply hiding and showing divs. That's not a problem at all.

If i go this route, can I already do the service works? 
Or will i still need to use other frameworks like Vue, react, Framework 7 etc to make a PWA? And if so, is it alright to mix jquery and PWA?

PS
No need to suggest to drop jquery and just use react etc. It is not an option for us for several reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 3 (along with the required JQuery library) for PWAs. So I cannot see why it would be a problem for you.

Comment: do i need to make it SPA though? or can PWA methods load other pages/links from cache? or will that result to a TIME OUT error?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Chrome Lighthouse tool to work through the list of items required to make your existing website a PWA. Look at the PWA section after you run the test.
Here is a video that explains that step by step.
https://youtu.be/Ay3zKmde3BM

Using Lighthouse will help you understand the exact items you need to add to YOUR website.
Here is the full checklist.
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist

Comment: tnx man. quick question, do i need to make it SPA though? or can PWA methods load other pages/links from cache? or will that result to a TIME OUT error? because i already have a multipage WEb App that loads data via AJAX and all, working on browser like normal. I guess my question is can i convert this straight to PWA or do i have to recode/design pages for PWA purpose? i guess what im saying is i'd like to maintain 1 code base for both web and pwa and perhaps use what i already have

Comment: SPA = Just another way of making a website. Most kinds of websites can have the pieces added to become a PWA. Many people get stopped from making their site a PWA because they cannot make their site HTTPS. This is one of the core requirements.

Answer (score 1):

**Question's little older but since I came across it let me answer this for posterity.**

You can use bootstrap+jquery while building a PWA, but we don't need them in particular. You can do it with simple HTML+CSS+JS.
Don't use CDN to load these libraries though, it may make them unavailable while the site/app is offline. Better way is to keep them on your server as local resources and cache them along with your other site/app assets.

And, absolutely no need to make your site/app SPA. We can cache more than 1 pages of our site to make them available offline.

Lastly we are still in wait for a good PWA specific framework as of Dec'21. That will make most of the current frontend libraries useless IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this site to obtain your goal :
https://progressier.com/quickstart/adding-pwa-features-to-your-jquery-site
"Adding PWA features to your jQuery site in 2023"
it helps you to create your mob app using many browser-based technologies.